# Mocking async dapper call to throw exception immediately throws during setup

Tags: .net-core, async-await, moq, xunit

When writing a unit test using XUnit, Dapper, Moq.Dapper, Visual Studio 2019, and .NET core 3.0, I'm trying to mock a call that will throw an exception using the code below which compiles correctly, but the test fails on the line where I'm setting up the call with the exception I'm configuring to throw.

```
[Fact]
public void CanRetryFailedTimeoutOperation()
{
    var mockConnection = new Mock<IDbConnection>()
        .SetupDapperAsync(c => c.QueryAsync<string>(It.IsAny<string>(), null, null, null, null))
        .ThrowsAsync(new TimeoutException());
}
```

Why would it throw the exception during the mock setup instead of the actual call which will happen later in the test (not shown here)?

Failed test result:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The operation has timed out.)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Moq.Dapper.DbCommandSetup.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`2.<SetupCommandAsync>b__1(Func`1 r)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Moq.Extensions.InvokePreserveStack(Delegate del, Object[] args)
   at Moq.MethodCall.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<SetCallbackResponse>b__1(Object[] args)
   at Moq.MethodCall.CallbackResponse.RespondTo(Invocation invocation)
   at Moq.MethodCall.Execute(Invocation invocation)
   at Moq.FindAndExecuteMatchingSetup.Handle(Invocation invocation, Mock mock)
   at Moq.Mock.Moq.IInterceptor.Intercept(Invocation invocation)
   at Moq.CastleProxyFactory.Interceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.ISetup`2Proxy.Returns(Func`1 valueFunction)
   at Moq.ReturnsExtensions.ThrowsAsync[TMock,TResult](IReturns`2 mock, Exception exception)
   at Tests.WhenUsingHdsRepository.CanRetryFailedTimeoutOperation() in Tests\WhenUsingHdsRepository.cs:line 57
System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Anyone has a solution for this yet?

Comment: Update: According to this link https://github.com/UnoSD/Moq.Dapper/issues/55 the library is no longer actively being developed unfortunately. @Geekn